# Email form: personalised 'thank you' page

Tags: vb.net

I have this in a VB.NET contact form:

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()

```
    mail.To.Add(txtEmail.Text)
    mail.From = New MailAddress("info@mySite.net")
    mail.Subject = "Contact Form"
    'mail.Bcc = New MailAddress

    mail.Body = txtName.Text & vbCrLf & txtComments.Text

    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("mail.server")
    smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("EMAIL ID", "PWD")

    smtp.Send(mail)

    Response.Redirect("thankyou.aspx" & mail.To)

    lblStatus.Text = "Your data has been submitted successfully"
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtEmail.Text = ""
    txtComments.Text = ""

End Sub
```

The mail.To in Response.Redirect is giving me an error:

Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection'.

I imagine I need to create a separate personalised aspx 'thank you' page, so I need a way of getting the user's name from the form field data.

Thanks for any advice.

Do you mean something like this:

Response.Redirect("thankyou.aspx" & Request.QueryString["email.Text"];

Answer (score 0):

Mail.To is a collection. Try `email.text` (which is what you passed to the mail address).